# SimpleCursorAdapter not working in MainActivity

Tags: android, listview

And please tell me am I using the String [] FROM correctly to map the cursor.

When I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter in my oncreate method of MainActivity it is giving error

> The method SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity, int, Cursor, String[], int[]) is undefined for the type MainActivity

I have checked the constructor in api docs according to which I am using it correctly

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)**
```

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView list;  
    private Cursor cursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.listview);      

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);

         String [] FROM = {cursor
            .getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)), cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))};

         int [] TO = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,cursor,FROM,TO);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

And here is my Layout listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think your error is list=(ListView)findViewById(R.layout.listview) change it it list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview)

Comment: @vinoth Thanks I have made the change but still the error is coming for SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: you are finding the view by id so you have to give it's id value like  R.id.listviewid.try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create `SimpleCursorAdapter` object as :

```
adapter =new  SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
         ^^^       android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,cursor,FROM,TO);
```

you forget to use `new` for creating   object of `SimpleCursorAdapter`

and use ListView  id to initialize `list` instead of `R.layout.listview`

```
list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Comment: Thanks it is the error but one more query am I using the String [] FROM correctly to map the cursor

Comment: @Er.NikhilAgrawal : yes you need to use `String [] FROM = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME),ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)};`

Comment: This is my last question the SimpleCursorAdapter is depricated in api level 11 So will it work on other apis after 11. or if I am using the new techniques introduced in api level 11 will they work on previous apis or not. What to use which can work on all pi levels